# Android Beacon Library entering non-existent null region

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon

I'm having a strange behavior when trying to detect regions with Android Beacon Library.

I defined 2 regions to monitor for beacons with specific ids.

Everytime I am in no region and enter one, didEnterRegion callback is triggered twice, one time for the expected region, and another time for a 'null' region.
If I enter a second region, it's triggered just once for the expected region.

Is this behavior normal? How can I make it not trigger for this 'null' region?

Here is a log that I printed to better show what's happening:

> 10-10 18:07:15.683: Got a didEnterRegion call, id1: 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
>
> 10-10 18:07:15.693: Got a didEnterRegion call, id1: null id2: null id3: null
>
> 10-10 18:07:22.946: Got a didEnterRegion call, id1: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>
> 10-10 18:07:41.880: got a didExitRegion 11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
>
> 10-10 18:07:57.913: got a didExitRegion 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>
> 10-10 18:07:57.914: got a didExitRegion null

And here is part of my code:

```
public class BeaconReferenceApplication extends Application implements BootstrapNotifier {
    private RegionBootstrap regionBootstrap;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // UPDATE: Trying to clear old regions.
        BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
        for (Region region: beaconManager.getMonitoredRegions()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Clearing old monitored region" + region);
            try {
                beaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        ArrayList<Identifier> ids1 = new ArrayList<>(1);
        ids1.add(Identifier.parse("11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111"));
        Region region1 = new Region("region1", ids1);

        ArrayList<Identifier> ids0 = new ArrayList<>(1);
        ids0.add(Identifier.parse("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"));
        Region region0 = new Region("region0", ids0);


        ArrayList<Region> regions = new ArrayList<>(2);
        regions.add(region0);
        regions.add(region1);
        regionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, regions);
    }
    @Override
    public void didEnterRegion(Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Got a didEnterRegion call, " + region);
    }
    @Override
    public void didExitRegion(Region region) {
        Log.i(TAG, "got a didExitRegion" + region.getId1());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect what is happening is that **the "null" region was persisted by an older version of your code.**  This would have happened when an older code version started monitoring for that region.

Understand that whenever you start monitoring for a region, the Android Beacon Library will persist those regions to non-volatile storage on your Android device, so when it restarts, it remembers the last region state and it knows whether to trigger a new region entry event.

The consequence of this is that if you ever want to clear out those old regions, you have to do so programatically.  **You can fix this with the following code:**

```
    // Stop monitoring all currently monitored regions
    for (Region region: mBeaconManager.getMonitoredRegions()) {
        mBeaconManager.stopMonitoringBeaconsInRegion(region);
    }        '
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed I had a Region 'null' in older versions, so it makes sense.  
But I tried adding your code inside onCreate, and apparently mBeaconManager.getMonitoredRegions() didn't return any region.  
I also tried mBeaconManager.removeAllMonitorNotifiers(), without success.

Comment: You probably can't put the code inside onCreate because the regions are not restored just yet... for a quick fix, try putting it inside the didEnterRegion callback.

Comment: But if I put it inside didEnterRegion, won't it also clear the regions I declared in onCreate? I tested and It is what appears to be happening.

Comment: I could solve it uninstalling the application, as I'm just testing it for now and I have nothing published. So your explanation of how the regions are persisted kind of already solved my problem, and I will mark it as accepted. But I would like to know if there is a way to solve it programatically. Maybe I just stop using 'null' regions in tests, so this doesn't happen again.